# Why node.js application auto-disconnect from Atlas MongoDB after some idle period and how to prevent this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

I have node.js app hosted on HEROKU and Atlas MongoDB database cluster.
In node app I connect to this db with standard command
`mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.jzycr.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true,useFindAndModify: false, useUnifiedTopology: true });`

I noticed issue that if there is no activity/no requests from users to app during a few hours my app automatically disconnects from Atlas db, I see it from log using mongoose.connection.readyState, it's equal to 0 (disconnected).

Is that normal behavior even with option useUnifiedTopology: true ?? I supposed that this flag auto-reconnect to database.
How to keep permanent connection to database even if there is long idle period? Should I use timer in my app to periodically check connection and manually re-connect again if mongoose.connection.readyState = 0 ?? What is the best pattern for this issue?

Comment: did you find a solution, i have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

```
let dbOptions = {
    dbName: process.env.MONGO_DATABASE_NAME,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    poolSize: process.env.MONGO_POOL_SIZE || 10,
    autoReconnect: true,
    reconnectInterval: 1000,
    reconnectTries: 10,
};

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, dbOptions);
// Create connection object.
const db = mongoose.connection;
```

Try this configuration

Comment: this configuration is not accpeted